# Cannot find namespace angular - angular1.5 with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tslint

I am using angulat 1.5 with typescript.
i have all the necessary configurations in tsconfig.json
when 9 run tslint, there are lot of errors in project :
which says

```
Cannot find namespace angular
```

ts config.json looks like

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",

]
```

}

tsd.d.ts file in typings folder contains :

```
 /// <reference path="angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-animate.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-cookies.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-sanitize.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="moment/moment-node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="moment/moment.d.ts" />
```

does anyone have the solution to fix that.

Comment: Please add your project config.

Comment: added tsd.d.ts and tsconfig.ts also i referred tsd.d.ts in app.ts(application main module where it b ootstraps.)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />` at the top, my guess is that the other reference may try to extend the angular namespace, which is not yet defined.